# In Views how to group by year in an archive and then split into months

Tags: 7, blocks, views

Views 3 - Create an archive for a given type grouped by year, then split in to months

```
Node Type
  |-Year(2015)
    |-September (node count(12))
    |-August (node count(15))
      ...
    |-February (node count(20))
    |-January (node count(30))
  |-Year(2014)
    |-December (node count(25))
    |-November (node count(35))
    |-October (node count(15))
```

By default archive block that just groups by month (i.e. September 2012 (node count)).I want to be in above format. In contextual filter by default archive block has passed created year + month.

I tried passing separately like created year and then month as separate month and still it didn't help.

Any help on this will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about grouping in views

Comment: @Reynolds: Archive block the format is in content.I don't know what field to group. In contextual filter it is passed like this created year + month.

Comment: You need to get date into fields twice. First date show year and you hide it. Second date show months. Where you set output format (ie html list or table) you set grouping to first date field that is hidden. Something like that.